# Python - How to divide numbers in list of lists?

Tags: python, arraylist, division

Hi i have been trying to get the mean of each sub-list using sum/length.

```
vectors = [[2.731018, 1.7550012, 2.3455532],
 [2.9210236, 3.2172325],
 [2.9255183, 2.66712, 2.7174947]]  

mean_vec = [sum(i)/len(i) for i in vectors]
```

Currently i am using the code above, however i am being prompted with this error message:

`ZeroDivisionError: division by zero`

The list above is just a sample. i have a much larger list of numbers. please advice me on how i should solve this

Comment: Your code works fine for me. You must have an empty list somewhere in your real dataset.

Comment: remove/ignore empty lists

Comment: alright problem solved hehe. my apologies for not checking properly. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your provided code `mean_vec = [sum(i)/len(i) for i in vectors]` can fail in certain scenarios

- `[]` #an empty list

Please add `len(i) != 0` in your code as show below

```
mean_vec = [sum(i)/len(i) for i in vectors if len(i) != 0]
```